# Complex number simple error

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors

Hey guys I'm new to c++ and every time I compile my code it keeps on saying I have an errorc2413 on a good amount of lines but I clearly have a semi colon there. This usually occurs whenever I type something such as ex. Complex.real. I was wondering if you can help me out?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Complex
{ 
private:
        double real;
      double imaginary;
public:
Complex()
{
    real = 0.0;
    imaginary = 0.0;
}
Complex(double r, double i)
{
    real = r;
    imaginary= i;
}

//Setters
void setReal(double r)
{
    real = r;
}
void setImaginary(double i)
{
    imaginary = i;
}

//Getters
double getReal()
{
    return real;
}// end getReal
double getImaginary()
{
    return imaginary;
}//end of getImaginary()

void output()
{
    cout<< real <<" + i"<< imaginary; 
}

Complex add(Complex a)
{
    Complex result;
    result.real= a.real + real;
    result.imaginary = a.imaginary+imaginary;
    return result;

}
Complex subtract(Complex a)
{
    Complex result;
    Complex.real = (real - a.real);
    Complex.imaginary = (imaginary - a.imaginary);
    return result;
}
Complex mul(Complex a)
{
    Complex result;
    Complex.real = (real*a.real)-(imaginary*a.imaginary);
    Complex.imaginary = (real*a.imaginary)+(imaginary*a.real);
    return result;
}
Complex div(Complex a)
{
    Complex result;
    result.real = 
    ((real*a.real)+(imaginary*a.imaginary))/((a.real*a.real)+(a.imaginary+a.imaginary));
    result.imaginary = 
        ((imaginary*a.real)-(real*a.imaginary))/((a.real*a.real)+(a.imaginary+a.imaginary));
    return result;
}
}//end complex class
```

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Complex Number Calculator, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  Calculator.cpp
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\calculator.cpp(3): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\complex.h(57): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\complex.h(57): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\complex.h(58): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\complex.h(58): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\complex.h(64): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\complex.h(64): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\complex.h(65): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>   1>c:\users\victor\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex number calculator\complex number calculator\complex.h(65): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Mind actually posting the error instead of a number that makes sense to very few people?

Comment: Try putting ; at before comment //end complex class..

Comment: suggestion: use ``const`` for your getters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there are a couple of errors, one the end of a class definition needs a `;`. It also looks like you have `Complex` in place of `result` in several places, for example:

```
Complex mul(Complex a)
{
    Complex result;
    Complex.real = (real*a.real)-(imaginary*a.imaginary);
    Complex.imaginary = (real*a.imaginary)+(imaginary*a.real);
    return result;
}
```

looks like it should be:

```
Complex mul(Complex a)
{
    Complex result;
    result.real = (real*a.real)-(imaginary*a.imaginary);
    result.imaginary = (real*a.imaginary)+(imaginary*a.real);
    return result;
}
```

Once I fix the above issues it looks like it compiles just fine. The function `subtract` also has the same issue as `mul`. Also the suggestion was made to use `const` on your getters, for example:

```
double getReal() const
{                ^^^^^
    return real;
}
```

This is good practice for methods you know should never alter any of the objects variables.

Comment: Yeah I just changed what you recommended and it compiles, Thank you!